# libnetcdf.so.18 in Debian 10.7

Tags: debian

I have just install Debian10.7 on my laptop, but for some software which I installed later there are error about its libraries:
1- psxy: error while loading shared libraries: libnetcdf.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

2-seisei: error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I checked Debian's package, but could not solve my problem. Could you please let me know how I can resolved then?
Thank you so much for taking time